# excel 2016 - delete rows based on multiple

Tags: excel

I am trying to delete rows when the date in column B is not present exactly 4 times for a given filekey in column C.  Sample data below:

```
A   B       C
Row Date      Filekey
2   1/6/2014    1
3   1/6/2014    1
4   1/6/2014    1
5   1/6/2014    1
6   1/7/2014    1
7   1/7/2014    1
8   1/8/2014    1
9   1/9/2014    1
10  1/9/2014    1
11  1/9/2014    1
12  1/9/2014    1
13  1/9/2014    1
14  1/6/2014    2
15  1/6/2014    2
16  1/6/2014    2
17  1/6/2014    2
```

The result I am looking for:

```
Row Date    Filekey
2   1/6/2014    1
3   1/6/2014    1
4   1/6/2014    1
5   1/6/2014    1
14  1/6/2014    2
15  1/6/2014    2
16  1/6/2014    2
17  1/6/2014    2
```

Please note that Row 6-7 were removed for only having 2 dates the same (too few), Row 8 for 1 date (too few), Rows 9-13 for 5 dates (too many)

Rows 14-17 were kept because:
there are exactly 4 rows with that date and it has a different filekey (column C) than rows 2-5 even though it shares those four dates.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In cell D2 use this formula and copy down:

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,C:C,C2)
```

Then filter on column D for everything other than 4 and delete those rows, then remove the filter and you can delete the formulas in column D